# Get sliced column values

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

I am working with iris.scale data set for analysis purpose. But in the processing how do i get sliced column values as after reading the data file,

```
df = pd.read_csv("../Data/iris.scale.csv", sep=' ', header=None, names=['class','S.lenght','S.width','P.lenght','P.width'])
print(df.head(3))

   class     S.lenght       S.width     P.lenght      P.width
     1        1:-0.555556    2:0.25      3:-0.864407     4:-0.916667
     1        1:-0.666667    2:-0.166667 3:-0.864407     4:-0.916667
     1        1:-0.833333    2:-0.08333  3:-0.830508     4:-0.916667
```

But how to get these sliced columns, like this one without any feature quotations, so it can be processed

```
class     S.lenght       S.width     P.lenght      P.width
     1        -0.555556    0.25       -0.864407     -0.916667
     1        -0.666667   -0.166667   -0.864407     -0.916667
     1        -0.833333   -0.08333    -0.830508     -0.916667
```

Comment: How big is ```iris.scale.csv```?  Would you add a few lines of the csv file?

Comment: its a very small data set, usually very good for bed testing

https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/datasets/multiclass/iris.scale

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) for create `DataFrame` with values with `:` only which are extracted by [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html), last cast output to `float`:

```
df=df.set_index('class').apply(lambda x: x.str.split(':').str[1]).astype(float).reset_index()
print (df)
   class  S.lenght   S.width  P.lenght   P.width
0      1 -0.555556  0.250000 -0.864407 -0.916667
1      1 -0.666667 -0.166667 -0.864407 -0.916667
2      1 -0.833333 -0.083330 -0.830508 -0.916667
```

Another solution with [`str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
df = df.set_index('class').apply(lambda x: x.str.extract(':(.*)', expand=False)).astype(float).reset_index()
print (df)
   class  S.lenght   S.width  P.lenght   P.width
0      1 -0.555556  0.250000 -0.864407 -0.916667
1      1 -0.666667 -0.166667 -0.864407 -0.916667
2      1 -0.833333 -0.083330 -0.830508 -0.916667
```

Answer (score 1):

## `pandas`

- `filter` to focus on correct columns
- `stack` + `str.split` + `unstack`
- `update`

***code***

```
df.update(
    df.filter(regex='S|P').stack().str.split(':').str[1].astype(float).unstack())
df

   class  S.lenght   S.width  P.lenght   P.width
0      1 -0.555556      0.25 -0.864407 -0.916667
1      1 -0.666667 -0.166667 -0.864407 -0.916667
2      1 -0.833333  -0.08333 -0.830508 -0.916667
```

## `numpy`

- `split` whole array at once
- construct new array
- slice and assign

***code***

```
s = np.core.defchararray.split(df.values[:, 1:].astype(str), ':').tolist()
df.iloc[:, 1:] = np.array(s)[:, :, 1].astype(float)

   class  S.lenght   S.width  P.lenght   P.width
0      1 -0.555556      0.25 -0.864407 -0.916667
1      1 -0.666667 -0.166667 -0.864407 -0.916667
2      1 -0.833333  -0.08333 -0.830508 -0.916667
```

Answer (score 0):

Pre-process the data prior to feeding it to Pandas to remove the excess

```
import re, io
with open("../Data/iris.scale.csv") as f:
    data = f.read()

p = r'[1-4]:'
data = re.sub(p, '', data)
```

Then you can either write the data to a new file before feeding it to Pandas or put it in a file-like object then feed it to Pandas.

```
#Python 2.7
data = io.BytesIO(data)
#Python 3x
#data = io.StringIO(data)
df = pd.read_csv(data, delim_whitespace = True, index_col = False, names=['class','S.lenght','S.width','P.lenght','P.width'])
```